# Do I need to install django separately for different python version?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

I had python version `2.7.3` and i wanted to learn django so i installed django version 1.8.2 on my ubuntu 12.0.4 .

```
invivtus@invictus:~/bin$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:08:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django 
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 8, 2, 'final', 0)
```

Then i read that best way yo work with django is to work on python version `3.3` so i installed python version 3.3.6 on my system where py is symbolic link pointing to /opt/python3.3/bin/python3.3

```
invictus@invictus:~/bin$ py
Python 3.3.6 (default, Jun 21 2015, 16:13:35) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

when I try and import django here i get error

```
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'django
```

I see django got installed my python 2.7 directory.

```
>>> import django
>>> django
<module 'django' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.pyc'>
```

How can i use this django with my 3.3.6 version. My default python version is 2.7.3
What are possible workout here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some of the comments said, you should be using a virtualenv to isolate your environments. You would do it like this:

1) Ensure you have `virtualenv` installed. On Ubuntu for instance, that would be package `virtualenv`.

2) Create a new, empty environment. You choose which python version it will be like this:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.4 env
```

3) That created an `env` folder. Activate the newly created environment:

```
. env/bin/activate
```

This updates your paths so now, when you run `python` or `pip` from this shell, they will execute in the context of your virtualenv.

4) Update the virtualenv (optional)

```
pip install -U pip
```

5) Install whatever packages you need. The recommended way is to have a `requirements.txt` file at the root of your project. You would pull them this way:

```
pip install -r myproject/requirements.txt
```

That's it. Use the `pip` command as usual. As long as you're working with the virtualenv active, your `python` command will only see the modules you explicitly install in it.

6) Don't forget to re-run  `. env/bin/activate` in every new shell. If you think you'll probably forget, you can add this to your `manage.py`:

```
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not hasattr(sys, 'real_prefix'):
        sys.stderr.write('Running outside of any virtualenv - did you forget to activate one?\n')
```

**What are the benefits?**

- You have an isolated environment for every project (no conflicts).
- You may use different versions of the same module in different projects.
- System updates will not break your project.
- You are not polluting your system with unmanaged files.
- You never run stuff as root, which means both added isolation, and the possibility of running your project without having root access to the system.
- As long as you keep your `requirements.txt` up to date (using `pip freeze`), you can rebuild the virtualenv on another system and it will work.

**[edit: using requirements.txt]**

That's just a file that has `pip install` specifications, one by line. It allows to rebuild the virtualenv from scratch easily. You can generate it from your current virtualenv using:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

So the idea is just to remember to re-run this command everytime you change your environment (installing, removing or upgrading some package).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to do the same with help of answer from Boolean provided in this link  http://askubuntu.com/questions/244544/how-do-i-install-python-3-3  . But can you explain more about requirements.txt here , how can i keep this updated.

Comment: Edited to answer your question ^^

Comment: Thanks , this along with few other post on SO , helped me set up a virtual environment for python 3.4 version. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Yes, each Python version has its own folder with installed packages. You'll have to install Django separately for Python 3.3. The same is true for every package that is not available by default.

(If you're using Python 3, why not go for the latest and greatest, 3.4?)

Comment: How will i add django package to my new version of python ? By default my version is 2.7.3 and i have my new python version at ./opt/python3.3
./opt/python3.3/bin/python3.3
as of now i have py added as a softlink pointing to  /opt/python3.3/bin/python3.3

Comment: You most likely have a `pip3` command, so use `pip3 install django`. If not, try `sudo apt-get install pip3`.

Comment: Also look into this: http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#shell-startup-file  Using virtual enviroments lets you keep all of your versions of django, and 3rd party modules segregated from your system stuff.

Comment: invictus@invictus:~$ sudo pip install django

`Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

Cleaning up...
Instead of using my new python version it goes for default python version of 2.7.3 installed on my system

Comment: seems like using pip3 has its downside. 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/401132/how-can-i-install-django-for-python-3-x

Comment: pip3 isn't the cause of those issues. Installing system-wide packages is. I would highly recommend using virtualenv (possibly with virtualenvwrapper) to isolate your python environments, but pip/pip3 is the de-facto standard to install python packages.